# Loading multiple php pages to phonegap via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I would like to load multiple php files from external database into phonegap via ajax.
I have tried by duplicating the javascript and change to txtHint1 at my 2nd script, but it couldn't work. So I'm wondering how do I load multiple external files into one html?

```
<!-- database --->
      <script>
          function showID(str)
          {
              if (str=="")
              {
                  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                  return;
              }
              if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
              else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                  {
                      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                  }
              }
              xmlhttp.open("GET","http://database.com/about.php"+str, true);
              xmlhttp.send();
          }
      </script>

      <script>
          function showHISTORY(str)
          {
              if (str=="")
              {
                  document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML="";
                  return;
              }
              if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
              else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                  {
                      document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                  }
              }
              xmlhttp.open("GET","http://database.com/history.php"+str, true);
              xmlhttp.send();
          }
      </script>


            <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" name="id" style="background:url() no-repeat; border-style:none; width:0px; height:0px;" onload="showID()" value="">
                <div id="txtHint"></div>

            <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" name="id" style="background:url() no-repeat; border-style:none; width:0px; height:0px;" onload="showHISTORY()" value="">
                <div id="txtHint1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions named `showID(str)`

There should just be one function named `showID(str)`

So have one called `showID(str)` and one called `showIDSomethingElse(str)`

Then change your HTML to

```
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" name="id" style="background:url() 
   no-repeat; border-style:none; width:0px; height:0px;" 
   onload="showID()" value="">

<div id="txtHint"></div>

<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" name="id" style="background:url() 
   no-repeat; border-style:none; width:0px; height:0px;" 
   onload="showIDSomethingElse()" value="">
```

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery? It makes AJAX a lot easier, try Krish R's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like,  You can keep one common ajax function and pass the parameter and fetch the respective page and update.

Javascript:

```
str="aboutus";
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://database.com/common.php?page="+str, true);
```

in common.php

```
switch($_GET['page']){
     case "aboutus":
         include("aboutus.php");
     break;
    ....

  }
```